# Equation explanier

Tags: equations, tabbing

How to fix this?

```
\begin{tabbing}
\phantom{$D_{n55}\ $}\= \kill
$k_{m,edge,k}$\> = Characteristic bending strength out of plane of CLT.\\
$f_{m,edge,l,k}$\> = Characteristic tensile strength parallel to grain of a single laminate.\\
\end{tabbing}
```

[image]

Comment: This question is phrased very poorly. What should be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous issues to your code, starting with the fact that it does not compile as it is.
There is no need for `\phantom`-anything, as `\kill` will delete this line and use it for tab positions only. Then every other line should end with `\\` and have the same number of tabbing commands (such as `\>`) as `\=`s in your `\kill` line. That's all.

Based on an educated guess of what you want to achieve, here is some code that actually compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabbing} $f_{m,edge,l,k}$ \= \kill
        $k_{m,edge,k}$ \> Characteristic bending strength out of plane of CLT.\\
        $f_{m,edge,l,k}$ \> Characteristic tensile strength parallel to grain of a single laminate.\\ 
    \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can use `\hspace*{3cm}` or equivalent commands in the `\kill` line as well.